# How does spark sc.textFile works?

Tags: apache-spark

```
JavaRDD<String> input = sc.textFile("data.txt");
```

For the above sample code in Spark, I know it returns distributed list of string. But individual string in that list is a `line` or `word` tokens of data.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string in your `rdd` equals a line in data.txt.

If the data in your data.txt file is some type of csv data, you can use the `spark-csv` package that will split the data into columns for you, so you don't have to parse the lines yourself.